# JavaEEアプリでアノテーションを用いて入力値を正の整数か検証したい

Tags: java-ee

JavaEEで部署管理アプリを作っています。
部署番号（deptNo）に正の整数以外を入力したら画面上でエラーが表示されるようにしたいです。
入力値検証アノテーションを使う方法をご教授頂きたくお願いします。

```
/**
 * 編集画面のバッキングBean
 */
@Model
@ViewScoped
public class EditBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private EditLogic logic;
    private Long id;
    private String deptName;
    private Integer deptNo;
    private String loc;
    private Integer versionNo;
    private boolean disableId;
```

```
    /**
     * 保存ボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String save(){
        logic.save(this);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage("", CommonUtil.getFacesInfoMessage("messages.add.complete"));
        return null;
    }
```

```
    /**
     * 保存処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void save(EditBean bean){
        Dept dept = new Dept();
        dept.setId(bean.getId());
        dept.setDeptName(bean.getDeptName());
        dept.setDeptNo(bean.getDeptNo());
        dept.setLoc(bean.getLoc());
        if(bean.getVersionNo() != null){
            dept.setVersionNo(bean.getVersionNo());
        }else{
        }

        if(bean.isDisableId()){
            // 更新
            dao.update(dept);
            bean.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo());
        }else{
            // 新規登録
            dao.insert(dept);
            bean.setDisableId(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: エラー画面やログに何か出力されていませんか？

Comment: 別の方に聞いたら、@patternは文字列に使用するのでIntegerには適さないとのことでした。。。特に何かエラー内容が出力されてはいないですね。

Comment: エラー画面には意図した入力エラーのメッセージが表示されているんですか？

Comment: いえ、用意していたエラー画面専用のxhtmlに遷移してしまう感じです。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試していませんが、おそらく、こんな感じではないかと思います。

```java
@Min(value = 1, message = "{deptNo.should.be.greater.than.1}")
private Integer deptNo;
```

`deptNo.should.be.greater.than.1`はメッセージのプロパティー・キーです。

Comment: 無事出来ました。何度も有難うございます。また宜しくお願いします。